# Jekyll and include_relative from sub-folders

Tags: jekyll

How can I use the `include_relative` tag correctly?

I have my folder layout and files like so.

my-account.html

- _includes

  - page-content

    - my-account

      - my-account.html
      - header.html
      - nav.html

In my-account.html I include the following file.

`{% include page-content/my-account/my-account.html %}`

All good.

However, inside the my-account.html from the includes folder, I am also calling header.html and nav.html

`{% include page-content/my-account/header.html %}`

`{% include page-content/my-account/nav.html %}`

Is there a way to use `include_relative` like this from the my-account.html since its in the same folder?

`{% include_relative header.html %}`

`{% include_relative nav.html %}`

Currently I get the error:

'./header.html' not found, so obviously the include_relative is not working.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try just `{% include header.html %}` and `{% include nav.html %}` for the last ones?

Comment: Yeah tried that but when you use the {% include %} tag, it goes to the root of the include folder, so it says header and nav not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to the file `my-account.html`:

```
{% include /page-content/my-account/header.html %}
{% include /page-content/my-account/nav.html %}
```

I've tested here with a similar structure and worked, then you should be ok. ;)

Comment: Thanks mate but I am already using that at the moment in my original question. Just wondering if there was a quicker way with relative.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't understand that's what you were currently using. As far as know, no, there's not another way to do that. If I understood Jekyll tutorials, this include_relative is for another purpose.